# Make a package installer for 2 file in mac os x

Tags: macos

I am new on mac . I have to create a package installer which is dmg file that package contain my application and my script file , I have to run my script at time of install.
one is Myapp.app and
another is script.sh

Answer (score 0):

You can use Package Maker to create a .pkg (which will install your program and run your script as a post-install script).

Download package maker at https://developer.apple.com/downloads under "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode"

If you MUST have it in a DMG at this point as well, simply create a DMG using Disk Utility, and add your files to that.

Comment: there is no package maker under this site

Comment: @user3906406, "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012" does include PackageMaker.  However, the Xcode 4.6 release notes said that PackageMaker was deprecated, and the `productbuild` command should be used instead.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my post you need "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode"